# sql query takes ages to complete

Tags: php, mysql, sql, key, relational-database

I have two relational tables of which i both need data. The first (Main) table contains about 90k rows. The secondary table contains about 200k plus rows.

I need to add some data of the secondary table to the results i get from the first table currently i do this in two parts:

First: i select the required rows from the Main table this goes super fast.

```
$records = getData($conn, "
SELECT id 
  from Main 
 where contains_tags is not null 
   and contains_mediums is not null 
   and contains_techniques is not null 
 limit 100
");
```

-
Then i go over each record to add the extra data from the secondary table but this takes ages (1 min for 100 records  50min - 100 min for 5k records. In the end i need to run this query for about 5-10k rows of the Main table). Is there a way to speed this process up?

```
foreach ($records as $r => $record) {
    $records[$r]['mediums'] = getData($conn, "SELECT medium from mediums where kleding_id = ".$record['id']."");
    kleding_id = ".$record['id']."");
}
```

This is the desired output after both queries finish:

```
[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 15
            [mediums] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [medium] => wol
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [medium] => katoen
                        )

                )

        )
```

So my question is how to run this query structure efficiently in as little as time as possible.

the Main table look like this:
[image]
the Secondary table looks like this:
[image]

If anything is unclear let me know so i can clarify.

Comment: have you proper index  on mediums.kleding_id  ????

Comment: not sure what you mean but Main.id corresponds with mediums.kleding_id and mediums.kleding_id is just a int column

Comment: Have you the an index for the column kleding_id on the tables mediums  or not  ??  eventually show your mediums   table scheda

Comment: @Jack no there can be multiple records in the secondary table that are associated with one record from the Main table

Comment: Why aren't you using a `JOIN`?

Comment: @scaisEdge i am not sure what you mean? the mediums table schema is the second image

Comment: the problem is not that the statement is slow. the problem is that a) php is slow and b) executing one statement hundret or thousand times is slow

Comment: You only need one query. Note that LIMIT without ORDER BY is fairly meaningless

Comment: For further help, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need  improve performance 
be sure you have a proper index table mediums column kleding_id

```
CREATE INDEX my_index  ON mediums (kleding_id);
```

remember that limit (for not recent db version)  normally work on the result  ..a and not break after the first 100 is reached

Comment: I think one query will be immeasurably faster than n queries

Comment: @Strawberry well if you know how i am all ears!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a single query. But it's for mysql Verison 5.7 & above.

```
SELECT id, GROUP_CONCAT(json_object('medium', mediums.medium))
FROM Main
LEFT JOIN mediums ON Main.id = mediums.kleding_id
WHERE contains_tags IS NOT NULL AND contains_mediums IS NOT NULL AND contains_techniques IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY Main.id
LIMIT 100
```

Also make sure you have a index on kleding_id.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to iterate over the first result and call the 2nd table multiple times. This will always be slow.

Try `inner join` to aggregate data from both tables in one sql statement.

```
SELECT
    Main.id,
    mediums.medium
from
    Main
inner join mediums on
    (
        Main.id = mediums.kleding_id
    )
where
    contains_tags is not null
    and contains_mediums is not null
    and contains_techniques is not null limit 100;
```

Comment: this kinda works but if there are multiple records in the mediums table associated with one record from the main table this record gets repead each time with a different value from the secondary table

Comment: But in that case, your query `SELECT medium from mediums where kleding_id = ".$record['id']."")` will return multiple rows too.

Comment: e.g. related to your screenshot `kleding_id = 10` for example. This will also return two rows in your sql statement

Comment: yes but like in the desired output these two rows are added to the main data from the Main table like an array. In your case i will get the record from the Main table twice each time with one of the values found in the secondary table.

Comment: Than add `order by mediums.kleding_id` and iterate one time in php to refactor the output to your php data structure. Imho, it's impossible to get such nested datastructure as a return value from sql. It's related to you programming language and what you're doing to it. In any case, it will be dramatically faster, because you're just make one sql execution and fetch data one time unline making hundrets or throusands of them.